# Как вывести диалоговое окно при нажатии на элемент меню?

Tags: android, listview

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на иконку корзины выскакивало диалоговое окно с двумя "кнопками" - да или нет. При нажатии на Да - происходило удаление.

Использую код:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


      if(item.getItemId() == R.id.deleteall) 
       {

//проверка, что listview не пустой
           ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
           int count = listDrinks.getCount();
           if(count > 0) {

               AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(listDrinks.getContext().getApplicationContext());
               ad.setTitle("Удалить все элементы из списка?"); 
               ad.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                       ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
                       db.deleteAll();
                       Cursor newcursor = db.getCur();
                       CursorAdapter adapter = (CursorAdapter) listDrinks.getAdapter();
                       adapter.changeCursor(newcursor);
                       cursor = newcursor;
                       //делаем неактивной кнопки при удалении всего списка
                       findViewById(R.id.deleteall).setEnabled(false);
                       findViewById(R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
               });
               ad.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                   }
               });
               ad.setCancelable(true);
               ad.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                   public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                   }
               });

               AlertDialog alert = ad.create();
               alert.show();

           }
       }
```

Приложение завершается с ошибкой:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Проблема где-то в темах. Возможно вы не тот диалог пользуете. Не из библиотеки поддержки... Или ещё чего... Выложите содержимое styles.xml

Comment: В качестве параметра в конструктор Builder не пробовали просто передавать "this" вместо getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 2):

Вместо этого listDrinks.getContext().getApplicationContext() нужно ставить Название класса.this